# Collecting SAAS user rule definitions in Rails 4 / Postgres App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

My application has many 3rd party commercial users. I want to introduce a feature where 3rd Party Admin, can define their own business rule logic.

The best solution that I can think of is to have Users select a variable class (ex. Customer.age) from a select dropdown and then have a form where they can manually type in rules in a predefined structure. The following will be examples of acceptable inputs (for the Customer.age example):

```
< 18 THEN "escalate"
> 25 THEN "accept"
> 65 THEN "reject"
IN [20, 21 , 22] THEN "congratulate"
BETWEEN [30, 40] THEN "revert"
```

The input structure obviously needs to adhere to strict validation rules. I see the structure working as #{OPERATOR} #{VALUE} THEN #{RESULT}. The value can obviously be an array, the others will obviously always be singular. Some rules that need to hold true are:

```
1. String has correct format
2. First param is all uppercase 
3. First param is a Valid operator
4. second param is a valid value / Array with valid values enclosed in square brackets.
5. Third Param is always "THEN"
6. Fourth param is in valid list.
```

What is the best way to approach this? Will it be REGEX? Or is there a different view on implementing this type of solution?

I don't mind making this system (validations) very strict as 3rd Party Admin will receive thorough training and documentation on the system.

Any advice will be gladly accepted!

Comment: Perhaps something like the gem [boolean_dsl](https://github.com/jobready/boolean_dsl) can help. With it, you can make custom rules like `age < 18` to validate within the context of ie a Customer object. Not exactly what you ask for, but I think it could be usable since the rules can be written by the end user. The main difference with your idea is that there is no `THEN` part, as that should live in your code and not in the rule-string.

Comment: @zwippie , thanks for this comment. I am also looking at the Wongi gem. It seems like it can be really helpful for something like this. A bigger piece of the puzzle seems like it's going to be collecting the input from the user in a form. As it needs to be strict enough not to allow "bad" rules, but also needs to be user friendly.

Comment: Here is another gem that matches your description quite close: [Aristotle](https://github.com/apprentus/aristotle).